# Find a splitting field for $x^4 - x^2 - 2$ over $\Bbb Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Find a splitting field for $x^4 - x^2 - 2$ over $\Bbb Z_3$.  I can see that $i$ (complex number) would be a root in $\Bbb Z_3(i)$, but I'm not sure if this would be the smallest splitting field, would there be a smaller one?

Comment: No complex number can be an element of $\mathbf Z_3$, because $3i\neq 0$.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying that $\Bbb Z_3(i)$ can't be a splitting field?  Because it's an extension field and $i^4 - i^2 - 2 = 0$ for $i \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: $\mathbf Z_3$ is not contained in $\mathbf C$: they do not have the same characteristic.

Comment: What he's trying to say is that strictly speaking, the name "complex numbers" only make sense over $\Bbb Q$, not over any finite field. You need to be more specific with what you mean by "$i$", for instance "an element that satisfies $i^2+1=0$".

Answer (score 10):

Notice that
$$x^4-x^2-2=x^4+2x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2$$
in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. Thus the splitting field has to contain $\alpha $ such that $\alpha ^2+1=0$; and if an extension contains such an $\alpha$, then it contains all the roots since the other root is $-\alpha$. Hence $(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)(\alpha)\cong \dfrac{(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)[t]}{(t^2+1)}$ is the splitting field.